# How to get User Profile form?

Tags: users, 8

How do I get the user Profile form? 
I tried the following:

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(ProfileForm::class);
```

but this results in :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null in
>   /www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityForm.php on line 77

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to load the user form programatically:

```
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();
$user_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('user')
  ->load($user->id());

$formObject = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getFormObject('user', 'default')
  ->setEntity($user_entity);

$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($formObject);
```

Comment: I would refer this answer. This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use it's namespace, like

```
use Drupal\user\ProfileForm;

 ..

$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(ProfileForm::class);
```

Or prefix the class, like

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\user\ProfileForm::class);
```

Or get it by 'name', like

```
 $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\user\ProfileForm');
```

---

> To fix your error, you need to pass a user object there, like this
>   (for the current user)

```
Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(ProfileForm::class, Drupal::currentUser());
```

Comment: I am using it's namespace. I get the same results from all of those methods you posted. Would it make a difference that I'm trying to get it in a custom module controller?

Comment: ah - you probably need to pass the user ;) see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

#### Drupal 7

I suggest another approach that seems easier.

```
global $user;
$user = user_load($user->uid);
// Loading the module to have access to the form.
module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
// Get the form.
$user_form = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user);
// Render the form.
return drupal_render($user_form);</code></pre>
```

With that you just have to know the `$form_id` by using `hook_form_alter()` and you can call all forms you want.

This solution is for Drupal 7.

Comment: The question is for Drupal 8.

Comment: Thanks, I know the question is for D8, but for me, who is still stuck supporting a D7 system, it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For entities like users use `entityFormBuilder()`:

```
$form = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($user);
```

`entityFormBuilder()` is available in all Controllers.

The first parameter is an entity, like node or user.

As second parameter you could choose a form. If empty 'default' is used and this is `ProfileForm` as defined in the user entity:

```
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\user\ProfileForm",
 *       "cancel" = "Drupal\user\Form\UserCancelForm",
 *       "register" = "Drupal\user\RegisterForm"
 *     },
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in my custom controller:

```
class UserEditController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Display the page content.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function content($user) {
    $entity = \Drupal::entityManager()
      ->getStorage('user')
      ->create(array());

    $formObject = \Drupal::entityManager()
      ->getFormObject('user', 'default')
      ->setEntity($entity);

    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($formObject);

    return [
      '#theme' => 'template_user_edit_form',
      '#user_edit_form' => $form,
    ];
  }
}
```

In the routing file I did:

```
 entity.user.edit_form:
   path: '/user/{user}/edit'
   defaults:
     _controller: '\Drupal\cusotm_module\Controller\UserEditController::content'
     _title: 'Update your profile'
   requirements:
     _permission: 'access content'
```

Big thanks to 4k4 who helped me getting the "default" to call the form !