# Add user edit form in a block D8

Tags: 8, forms, users

I'm trying to add the user edit form in a block.
I created a custom module

```
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\user\ProfileForm;


class EditUserBlock extends BlockBase{

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(ProfileForm::class, \Drupal::currentUser());

    return $form;
  }
}
```

but it doesn't render the form.

Sorry but I'm pretty new to D8.

Comment: this is a similar question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207884/how-to-get-user-profile-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an entity form and you need [EntityFormBuilder::getForm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFormBuilder.php/function/EntityFormBuilder%3A%3AgetForm/8.3.x) to build this form. After you have injected the entity form builder and the necessary user storage and current user services in the block plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a Profile Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *  id = "profile_block",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("Profile Block"),
 * )
 */
class ProfileBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilderInterface
   */
  protected $entityFormBuilder;

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface
   */
  protected $userStorage;

  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, EntityFormBuilderInterface $entity_form_builder, AccountInterface $current_user, EntityStorageInterface $user_storage) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->entityFormBuilder = $entity_form_builder;
    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
    $this->userStorage = $user_storage;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('entity.form_builder'),
      $container->get('current_user'),
      $container->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('user')
    );
  }
```

you can build the profile form for the current user with two lines of code:

```
  public function build() {
    $user = $this->userStorage->load($this->currentUser->id());
    return $this->entityFormBuilder->getForm($user);
  }

}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! This might be a little off-topic, but do you know how I would do this for the user specified in the route rather than for the current user?